# Make ping on linux behave like ping on Mac OSX

Tags: linux, osx, ping

After a lot of internet searching and trying just about every option on the man page, I'm stumped.

I use Linux and Mac both regularly in any given day. I've noticed that I prefer the ping command's behavior on Mac and I became interested in finding a way to replicate it on Linux, assuming there must be some combination of arguments to do so. None yet that I can find.

On Mac, if I ping a host, by default it will print something every single second: ping success or ping fail.

On Linux, the default behavior appears to be to batch failure responses into 3-4 second chunks. If you run them side-by-side pinging a dead IP, Mac ping will update every second, Linux will update every 3-4. The behavior is identical if the host is up: they both print a response every second.

I much prefer the Mac behavior of printing every second, success or fail. I have been unable to find any combination of options to get Linux ping to work the same.

There is the "-O" option, which is the closest I've gotten, but it's needlessly verbose: it print two lines for every failed ping instead of just one.

Has anyone else found the right combination of arguments to make Linux ping behave the same as Mac ping?

Comment: Try `-W 1`, and `-w 1`

Comment: I second using `-W 1` since it is likely that the linux failures are waiting for a slow reply. The problem with timeouts is that they are always either too short or too long -- and if the latency to your remote host is greater than 1s then adding `-W 1` will give you false negatives.

Comment: Testing on Arch, Fedora, Debian and Ubuntu, -W 1 still has the buffering I described. Output pauses for 3-4 seconds and then it spits out 3-4 lines. On the Mac output is consistently printed out every second. Try it. No, this is not a huge deal, but it's annoying to me that it buffers and I was hoping there was an easy way to make it behave like Mac's ping.